# Simple php dom parser - find element

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have the following code which gets links from specific links:

```
if($site === 'Test') {  
   $list = $html->find('div.most-viewed-section ol li'); 
   foreach($list as $item) { 
      $link = $item->find('a', 0)->href; 
      $headline = $item->find('a', 0)->innertext; 
      $image = $item->find('span.image-optional a img', 0); 
          if($image) { 
          $image = $image->src; 
          } 
   $Post[] = array('link' => $link, 'headline' => $headline, 'image' => $image); 
  } 
}
```

But now what i want to do is also find elements in the following link:

```
$link = $item->find('a', 0)->href;
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to chain.. if there was an image within the a tag and you wanted to get the image src, something like the below should work:

```
$image = $item->find('a', 0)->find('img', 0)->src;
```